# Rails event start_time+length=end_time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model

```
 create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "start"
    t.datetime "end"
```

How to add a "duration value", so that "end"="start+duration"?

Comment: You need `duration` as DB column or Active record attribute?

Comment: `end` is a bad name for column. sql also have `end`, `BEGIN .. END`

Comment: I want start_time & end_time as DB columns.
Idea: set .a "duration" attribute in _form, give it values like "30 min, 60 min".
When user chooses the "duration" in _form, "end_time" is auto changed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a duration, as long as you have the initial and the final date you can easily compute the duration on the fly.

You can have a duration in your model

```
def duration
  end_time - start_time
end
```

Also, you should not use `end` as a field name, because it is a reserved keyword in Ruby and it may conflict with the parser in some cases. For example, you won't be able to write

```
def duration
   end - start
end
```

If instead, you want to create a database column, then simply create an integer `duration` attribute and you can use either an active record callback to compute the duration when the record is saved.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed end & start to end_time & start_time.

Comment: I want it to be like "end_time = start_time + duration". => to create the "duration attribute....

Comment: Then follow the instructions I posted above, but compute the `end_time` rather then `duration`.

Comment: & how do I add "duration" as a "minutes" input field in _form?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I changed `start` to `start_time`;

Deleted `end` from db;

Created `duration:integer` in db;

in model:

`def end_time
start_time + duration*60
end`

this way, I can input `start_time`, `duration`, => see `end_time`